# Spring Boot version upgraded to 2.4.10 throwing issue of ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.SleuthProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Changed spring boot version `2.3.10.RELEASE` to `2.4.10` . Also changed the `spring-cloud` version to `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.0` . However I am getting below error. I am not using any functionality of `cloud-sleuth`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.SleuthProperties]**
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:446)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193)
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.SleuthProperties**
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324)
    ... 114 more
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation:

https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth#overview

It should be like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${release.train.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I tried adding spring-cloud-starter-sleuth. but it causes the same issue.

Comment: Kindly show your pom @user16509810

Comment: I also tried to add "implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:2.2.7.RELEASE'" then I am getting error - Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'spring.sleuth.baggage-keys' defined in class path resource